# Minimum number of steps to reach a position

Tags: algorithm

I am on a infinite length number line, Currently at position zero. Each step I can only take `R units` to right and `L units` to left. What is the minimum number of steps required to reach a `point H.`

Can I know the algorithm used to solve this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about a concrete programming question.

Comment: You should provide more details: Is the list sorted, can we take steps with 1 Units ?

Comment: @DSM: perhaps this should be moved to `programmers SE`?

Comment: What is the list? No steps are either R units right or L units left

Comment: List is the data structure to make infinite number of data elements in a row. Like a infinite array.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extended Euclidean algorithm to solve this problem efficiently. It actually finds a solution for
`A * x + B * y = gcd(A, B)` equation, but your problem is can be easily reduced to this one. It has `O(log(max(A, B))` time complexity under the assumption that `A` and `B` fit into a standard integer type(that is, do not require bignums). You can read more about it, for example, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm.